# Updating mounted or mounting component warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following warning in my tests:

```
Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the ProtectedRoute component.
```

So I checked my ProtectedRoute component. This component is built upon the `Route` component from `react-router` and checks if user is logged in before rendering route. Here is the component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Authentication } from 'local-authentication-service';

const renderMergedProps = (component, ...otherProps) => {
  const finalProps = Object.assign({}, ...otherProps);
  return (
    React.createElement(component, finalProps)
  );
};

class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { loading: true };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const user = await Authentication.getUser();
      this.setState({ user, loading: false });
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, user } = this.state;
    const { component, ...otherProps } = this.props;

    if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

    return user ? <Route render={routeProps => renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, { user }, otherProps)} /> : <Redirect to="/auth/login" />;
  }
}

ProtectedRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.element,
    PropTypes.func,
  ]).isRequired,
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

As far as I see, the only state change is done in `componentDidMount()` so it should not be throwing this error.
Where should I check to solve this warning ?

Thank you !

Comment: On a side note, why are you using React.createElement in your code? You can easily use JSX and make your code more declarative/easier to read.

Comment: Hey julien did you remove your vote and acceptance from the answer?

Answer (score 0):

### By the time your async auth call completes, you've already redirected your user to /auth/login and unmounted ProtectedRoute. When the auth call finally completes, it tries to update ProtectedRoute's state. That's when React gives you this nice message saying you are trying to update a component which is no longer there. Read for details :)

It's a bit tricky but here's what's happening:

On the initial mounting of the component, `componentDidMount` is invoked and fires off your `Authentication.getUser` call. Since it's async, it does run immediately and instead gets added to the the javascript event loop. At this point, the code continues on. Since the auth call hasn't actually completed, you have no user of of yet. In your render method you specify to redirect the viewer to `/auth/login` if there is no user. Since this is the case, you are redirected and your component ends up unmounting.

Do you see where I am going?

The event loop finally decides that no other synchronous code needs to be ran and gives that sitting authentication call a chance to fire. It does its thing and tries to update the state based on where there is/is not a user. But component is no longer there. :(

Then you get this nice message from the great react gods. But you're a coder, and you learn from this and this starts to happen less and less.

### How can you avoid this?

You need your component state to keep track of whether or not your auth call has completed. Only after the call is completed should you try to check if there is/isn't a user. Only then, if a user is not present should you redirect.

Maybe an `isFetchingUser` state property would suffice? Then, once `isFetchingUser` is `false` and `user` does not exist you redirect, otherwise if `isFetchingUser` is `true`, you can show either a loading message, a spinner or just a white screen since your async call should hopefully be very fast.

Comment: Your `isFetchingUser` is my `loading` state property... I still don't understand how it can render one of the routes while `this.state.loading` is true (set directly in the component constructor).

Comment: 1. set intial loading state to `true`. In `componentDidMount`, fire off the auth call, and regardless of whether the it returns a user or not, call setState and set loading to false once the async call completes (you have this already). Then, in `render`, check if `this.state.loading` is `true`. If it is, display a loading message or spinner or nothing at all. If `this.state.loading` is `false`, then check if there is a `this.state.user` exists. If so, display logged in content. if not, that means your auth call returned a 403 unauthorized and redirect the user to login page.

Comment: Sorry I meant 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Well... if you just look at the code of my component, it's exactly what I am doing. Or at least try to do.

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.?**

Before `componentDidMount` life cycle,`render` is called.

In `render`,

```
 return user ? 
 <Route render={routeProps => renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, { user }, otherProps)} /> 
 : <Redirect to="/auth/login" />;
```

initially `user` is evaluated as a `false` resulted in `Redirect`  route is getting called. So, current `ProtectedRoute` component is getting unmounted.

But at the same time,you are settting `setState` inside `componentDidMount`   which not going to execute as your component getting unmounted.

Because of this, you are getting above warning.